# Question on theory from original GBM article

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, mathematics, gbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I am reading the [original gradient boosting machine article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-5/Greedy-function-approximation-A-gradient-boosting-machine/10.1214/aos/1013203451.full) and, maybe because my statistics are a bit rusty, have a few questions on one section.

In section `3. Finite Data` the following claim is made about the previously introduced nonparametric approach to function approximation.

> This nonparametric approach breaks down when the joint
> distribution of $(y, \bf{x})$ is estimated by a finite data sample $\{y_i, \bf{x_i}\}^N_1$. In this
> case $E_y[\cdot|\bf{x}]$ cannot be estimated accurately by its data value at each $\bf{x_i}$ ...

I am at a complete lack of understanding for this claim and justification, again perhaps because I am missing some stats. I have the following questions:

1. What specifically about the **finite data** is causing this?
2. Why is the nonparametric function approximation effected by this and **not the parametric form**